# try to understand for loops and getchar() in c

Tags: c, for-loop, getchar

I'm new to C and I'm trying to understand how the for loops work.

My code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   int a;
   for( a = 0; a < 4; a++ )
   {
      printf("value of a: %d\n", a);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

I get my expected output which is 4 times the value of a but when I do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   char c;
   int a;
   for( a = 0; a < 4; a++ )
   {
      printf("value of a: %d\n", a);
      printf("Enter character: ");
      c = getchar();
      printf("Character entered: ");
      putchar(c);
      printf("\n");
   }
   return(0);
}
```

I get

> value of a: 0 Enter character: m Character entered: m value of a: 1
>   Enter character: Character entered:
>
> value of a: 2 Enter character: a Character entered: a value of a: 3
>   Enter character: Character entered:

It somehow over jumps the two of the `getChar()`, why?

**SOLUTION** 
Go it to work thanks to the comments:

```
int i;       
for( a = 0; a < 4; a++ )
{
    printf("Enter character: ");
    c = getchar();
    while ((i = getchar()) != '\n' && i != EOF)
    printf("Character entered: ");
    putchar(c);      
}
```

Comment: `'\n'`. Why does *every* c-beginner forget about `'\n'`?

Comment: use the `\n` in the line after `getchar`. To clear it.. `while(getchar() != '\n');` should suffice.

Comment: ahh ok thanks! wanna post it as an answer then I will accept it. @EOF: probably because there are no '\n' on tutorialspoint. I don't think your comment is very helpful though

Comment: **char c;** should be **int c** because the return of getchar which is **int**.

Comment: ah right, ok thanks !

Comment: `while (getchar() != '\n')` ... nice infinite loop if `stdin` happens to be a file or an error is encountered.

Comment: @CareyGregory what do you mean?

Comment: Suppose I ran your program like this:  `foo < input.dat` and suppose input.dat was empty. What would `getchar` do? It will return `EOF` indicating that either an error or end-of-file occurred. Well, since `EOF` doesn't match `\n` the loop will continue infinitely.

Comment: what would be the right approach then?

Comment: Test for a return value of `EOF` from `getchar` and break out of the loop if you encounter it. Something like this: `while ((i = getchar()) != '\n' && i != EOF)`. And note that `i` must be an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: ok thanks, if you post it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, the `ENTER` key results in as a newline (`\n`) character, and `getchar` reads and returns it after each letter.
You also should pay attention to errors or end-of-file conditions.

Here's a more robust version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   char c;
   int a;
   for(a=0; a<4; a++)
   {
      printf("value of a: %d\n", a);
      printf("Enter character: ");
      do {
          c = getchar();
      } while(c == '\n'); // ignore newlines
      if(c == EOF) break; // end of input or error
      printf("Character entered: %c\n",c);
   }
   return(0);
}
```

This has the added benefit (or not) that duplicated ENTER keys are ignored. Also, if you type two characters before the ENTER, they will be both read the same as if each were typed separatedly. Again, this might be good or not, depending on what you want to happen. But you should ask yourself what do you want to happen.